# Error: Un documento XML debe contener un elemento de nivel de raíz - C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

Creo que no hay mucho mas por decir, el titulo lo dice todo, tengo una app en Xamarin.Android que me genera el siguiente error:

```
un documento XML debe contener un elemento de nivel de raíz
```

Se borro el archivo desde la ruta de acceso y la app lo volvió a generar.

Ahora bien, abro error por error y me sale "values.xml" vacio, le agrego texto uno por uno, lo mando a recompilar y vuelve a lo mismo. Otra vez los errores y otra vez me sale en limpio "values.xml".

No entiendo que pasa.

[image: Error]

[image: ErrorDespuesDeRecompilar]

Y si no es ese error entonces me saca este:

```
"java.exe" salió con el código 1.
```

Pero uno de esos dos y no la hago pasar de ahi. He probado de todo en la web ya.

[image: javaexe]

Salida / Output:

```
1>------ Operación Recompilar todo iniciada: proyecto: PersonalA, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2084,5): warning MSB3245: No se pudo resolver esta referencia. No se encuentra el ensamblado "Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces.Streaming, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8341efbf9a4dc8c9, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Compruebe si el ensamblado existe en el disco. Si el código necesita esta referencia, podrían producirse errores de compilación.
1>C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PersonalA\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.10.0\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(88,3): warning XBD100: ItemGroup `XamarinBuildDownloadRestoreAssemblyAar` is no longer supported.  If your build is failing, revert to an older Xamarin.Build.Download version, or migrate your packages to use the new `XamarinBuildDownloadAndroidAarLibrary` ItemGroup.  If your build is succeeding it is safe to ignore this warning.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(161,3): warning APT2000: warn: removing resource com.companyname.spoiled:string/com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender without required default value.

1>  PersonalA -> C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PersonalA\PersonalA\bin\Debug\PersonalA.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(226,3): warning APT2000: warn: removing resource com.companyname.spoiled:string/com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender without required default value.
1>C:\SolucionarJava1\android-sdk\\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt : warning XA4304: No se encontró el archivo de configuración de ProGuard "C:\SolucionarJava1\android-sdk\\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.D8.targets(51,5): error MSB6006: "java.exe" salió con el código 1.
========== Recompilar todo: 0 correctos, 1 incorrectos, 0 omitidos ==========
```

Comment: Necesitas iniciar tu archivo xml con el encabezado correspondiente <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Me sigue generando el error aunque le agregue esa etiqueta.